# Telegram Bot Не могу создать последовательное заполнение списка

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Создаю бота через библиотеку telebot и не могу разобраться как зациклить вопросы бота чтобы он ждал ответ и затем продолжал спрашивать пока не закончится список

Пример:
Есть список `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` и для каждого элемента списка бот должен получить значение 0 или 1 и добавлять его во второй список по итогу сопоставляемый с первым

```
бот:-a?
пользователь:-1
бот:-b?
пользователь:-0
бот:-c?
пользователь:-1
бот:-d?
пользователь:-1
бот:-e?
пользователь:-0
бот:-a1, b0, c1, d1, e0
```

мой код:

```
lines = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
stat = []

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text_handler(message):
    global i
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if message.text =="A":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lines[i])
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, s_h)

def s_h(message):
    if message.text == "0":
        stat.append(0)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lines[i]+stat[i])
    elif message.text == "1":
        stat.append(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lines[i]+stat[i])

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

он то выдает ошибку то делает вообще не то и я не понимаю как это исправить

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
d = {}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def one(message, index=None):
    if index is None:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lines[0])
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, two, msg.text)
    else:
        if index > len(lines) - 1:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'список закончен')
        else:
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lines[index])
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, two, msg.text)


def two(message, text):
    if '0' or '1' in message.text:
        d[text] = message.text
        one(message, lines.index(text) + 1)

        print(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Функция `one` принимает два аргумента - `message` и `index`

При первом запуске `index` = None поэтому отправляем элемент из списка с нулевым индексом.
Регистрируем обработчик следующего шага, который вызывает функцию two с текстом сообщения. Обратите внимание, что мы в `register_next_step_handler` три аргумента: отправляемое сообщение, функция следующего шага и текст из отправленного ботом сообщения.

Если `index` указан, то проверяется, не закончился ли список `lines`.
Если не закончился, отправляется следующее сообщение из списка по индексу элемента, и также регистрируется обработчик для функции two.

Функция `two` принимает два аргумента - `message` и `text` (текст из отправленного ботом сообщения).

Проверяем, содержит ли текст сообщения пользователя '0' или '1'. Если условие выполняется, то значение `message.text` сохраняется в словарь `d` под ключом `text` (текст из отправленного ботом сообщения).

Затем вызывается функция `one` с увеличенным индексом, чтобы продолжить отправку следующего сообщения из списка `lines`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вывод в консоль:

```
{'a': '1'}
{'a': '1', 'b': '1'}
{'a': '1', 'b': '1', 'c': '1'}
{'a': '1', 'b': '1', 'c': '1', 'd': '1'}
{'a': '1', 'b': '1', 'c': '1', 'd': '1', 'e': '1'}
```

p.s. `global` зло.